# Why can't I copy and paste image in some position using OpenCV when it is declared as varIable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv

I'm trying to crop a particular portion of two images and swap the position of those image in the main image using OpenCV.

Below is the code I'm using to perform above requirement

```
    image1 = img[198:238, 456:654]
    image2 = img[120:282, 487:534]
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image1, (90, 221)) 
    resized_image1 = cv2.resize(image2, (211, 90)) 
    img[120:282, 487:534] = resized_image
    img[198:238, 456:654] = resized_image1
    cv2.imwrite('01.png',img)
```

above code successfully swap the two image position but when I pass value dynamically I declare the position of image to be sliced as variable, say 'positiion' when I use this variable image won't get swaped as shown in below example

```
    position[0] = img[198:238, 456:654]
    position[1] = img[120:282, 487:534]
    image1 = position[0]
    image2 = position[1]
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image1, (90, 221)) 
    resized_image1 = cv2.resize(image2, (211, 90)) 
    position[1] = resized_image
    position[0] = resized_image1
    cv2.imwrite('01.png',img)
```

here image remains same as it before no swaping occurs. `image1 = position[0]` will crop the image at the given position but when I try to paste the image using  `position[1] = resized_image` nothing actually happens expected to swap the image. So whats happening why swapping doesn't occur.How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using img[198:238, 456:654] returns a new image, **not** a reference to the original image. So position[0] actually holds a new image with the swapped region of interest.

You can solve this by creating a list of tuples with the x/y values of each RoI and use these to resize and swap the RoI's.